# Wine error "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows"

Tags: windows, qt, mono, wine, logitech-gaming-software

I´ve been working on porting a program called "Logitech Gaming software" to mac. I've downloaded a wrapper called "steamliner"

http://portingteam.com/files/file/8146-steamliner/

> I downloaded this steam wrapper because it had the .net program "mono" and  already set windows 7 system...
>   And when i run the installer for the "Logitech Gaming software" i get an error  called

I've been on a lot of sites, that says that i should do some cmd commands or install some programs. I haven't made any terminal commands, but i have tried to install two program called "mingw" and "qt-opensource-windows-x86-1.6.0-8"

> Mingw: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net

I didn't have any success installing "qt-opensource-windows-x86-1.6.0-8" because of an error called "Connection Closed".

But i did have success installing "Mingw".

> Does anyone have an idea to fix this error.

**by the way i'm using wine to port the program, and i'm not very good, so would you please answer in non-geek language :)**

Comment: `I´ve been working on porting a program called "Logitech Gaming software" to mac` - You can download native LGS for MacOS from [official download page](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025298053-Logitech-Gaming-Software)